# Choosing a portable encryption library

Tags: c, encryption, package, shared-libraries, portability

I am developing a utility that, among other things, encrypts data using a pass-phrase supplied by the user. I don't have much experience writing good and portable code so I am trying to learn how to do it well. What is the best library to use to perform hashing and encryption functions?

To clarify, I'm not looking for a library with the best functionality, I am looking for a library which is available on most operating systems and commonly installed on many. I know I'm not going to find a library that is installed by default on most operating systems, but I would like to pick one that provides the easiest installation for the majority of users.

I have looked at vanilla installations of Windows 7 (Cygwin), Mac OS X 10.8, Debian 6.0.5, and Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and the only thing they all have in common is `crypt` which I understand is not recommended due to using a weak encryption algorithm with a limited key size.

At the moment I am considering using `libmcrypt` and `mhash` as these are available via aptitude on both Debian and Ubuntu (and from what I can tell most other distributions of Linux), can be installed on Mac OS X via MacPorts or Homebrew, and are available in the Cygwin installer for Windows. They are also available for FreeBSD, OpenBSD, and NetBSD.

I would very much appreciate some help in choosing the best library to use, as well as pointing out other factors that I may not have considered.

Comment: I really hate to say it, but... OpenSSL is widely used on every OS and has the kitchen sink. Not sure I'm happy recommending it though, having had some bad experiences in the past (plus the caution demanded by the track record of some of its components).

Comment: What is the licensing for your app? Can you build and link a static library into your app, so that you don't need to worry about what's installed on end users' computers? OpenSSL and PolarSSL are open source options: http://www.openssl.org/ and https://polarssl.org/

Comment: stick with best practices. use methodologies and routines that have been well vetted as opposed to making a home brew such as IV's and salts. maybe have that passphrase come over ssl and not in the clear.

Comment: @NicholasWilson I'll have a look at OpenSSL but it seemed a bit overkill just for some simple encryption/decryption and hashing.

Comment: @AlexReynolds I've only just started developing so I guess the license can be whatever I want it to be, but as I said above, I'm a bit hesitant in including the kitchen sink in my program when I only need one of the taps.

Comment: @DrewPierce That's what I'm trying to do, but due to my lack of experience, I'm trying to find out what good practices actually are, hence my question. Also, there is no network interaction with this program, it is all run by the user on their computer so I don't need to worry about the password being transmitted in the clear. (Unless they remotely log on to their computer using something like telnet)

Comment: With PolarSSL, it's pretty simple to leave out the kitchen sink and just build the pieces you want. To do this (for example, with v1.2.0), edit the `OBJS` variable in `polarssl-1.2.0/library/Makefile` and comment out unwanted objects. When running `make`, you'll only get the pieces you need. I'll bet that OpenSSL has something similar.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Looks pretty good, do you have any references regarding packaging other libraries within my own program, and any licensing issues this may create?

Comment: Nope, that's all I have. Hopefully it gets you started though.